# Passing ng-repeat object data from html to controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn angular by creating some small app.

How do i pass the data in the ng-click directive below from the html to my angular controller function?

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="movie in movies.Search | filter:search | orderBy:'-Year'">
   <td><a ng-href='#here' ng-click="getMovie({{movie.imdbID}})">{{movie.Title}}</a></td>
</tr>
</table
```

The above way gives me a syntax error. Passing the entire the movie object as getMovie(movie) sends it as a string which I can't access in the controller. I want to pass only the movie.imdbID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getMovie(movie.imdbID)
```

You're already inside an angular expression. So you don't need any mustache.

And no, `getMovie(movie)` doesn't pass the movie as a string. It passes a reference to the movie object.